# increasing the contents of a pcap file

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I want to store large number of packets in a pcap file (say around 200000) and then send it using tcpreplay . The problem is the loop option in tcpreplay sends at a very low speed .
Now I am capturing packets using wireshark but wireshark does not respond after sending a lot of packets . How can i increase the length of the pcap file by multiplying the number of packets already stored in it ? How can I achieve good throughput using tcpreplay?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to multiple a single pcap, consider the mergecap command, shipped with wireshark.

Regarding the packet pumping speed of tcpreplay take a look at its FAQs, and in particular consider the -T option to pick a timer mechanism that works well. I've found rdtsc to work very well. Also consider using a short trace that fits into memory, and iterating playback of that, to avoid disk I/O. For this, consider the -K option.